# Powershell cmdlet params in nant

Tags: .net, powershell, continuous-integration, nant

I have an nant build where I am trying to call a powershell cmdlet like below:

```
<exec program="powershell.exe" commandline='.\Download.ps1 ${dir}' />
```

This works fine as long as there dir path doesn't contain white spaces and throws below error:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument .....
```

I tried below to fix this but that doesn't work.

```
<exec program="powershell.exe" commandline='.\Download.ps1 "${dir}"' />
```

Comment: What does your Param statement in the download.ps1 look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got is fixed by modifying the exec task as:

```
<exec program="powershell.exe" commandline=".\Download.ps1 '${dir}'" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
<exec program="powershell.exe">
    <arg value=".\Download.ps1"/>
    <arg value="${dir}"/>
</exec>
```